# Self hosted group email solution (like yahoo or google groups)

Tags: email, cms

Are there any solutions out there that you can host yourself that provide similar functionality to yahoo and google groups?

Users must be able to communicate exclusively via email, but optionally browse via web as well. Would prefer to have files/links section as well.

Comment: Yahoo and Google Groups aren't email solutions. They're discussion boards. They have email subscription features, but you use your own email account.

Comment: Yes, but I'm yet to find a typical discussion board with seamless interraction with email. The only discussion boards I've found are unable to operate independent of the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for mailing-list softwares, for example [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html).

Comment: This isn't really what I wanted, but its the closest thing out there.